# Debugging shell scripts with line numbers

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I inherited a over 700 line shell script and noticed that when I ran the script it spits out error at some point of execution.

E.g error that I see on the console is something like

```
cat: /Wreck/wreck_module.rb: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to use `set -x` and most of the tips from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script), however I noticed that all the output that I was getting were pretty noisy.

Is there a way to get the exact line number of where a shell command returned a non-zero status?

Comment: What shell are you using exactly?

Comment: I am using the bash shell

Comment: Use `bash -vx` to execute your shell script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this at the top of the script you want to debug:

```
#!/bin/bash
function trace_line(){
  caller
}
trap trace_line debug
```

and perhaps redirect the output to a file for easy analysis.

Comment: What does this do? Is "caller" a built-in shell feature? Edit: [yes, it is.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19323)

Comment: When I put it in the first few lines of the script, it seems that it cannot print the line number in the **function**, how can I modify it